# How do I order a Group result, in Linq?

Tags: linq, sql-order-by, group-by

I have the following linq query, which works fine. I'm not sure how i order the group'd result.

```
from a in Audits
join u in Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId
group a by a.UserId into g
select new { UserId = g.Key, Score = g.Sum(x => x.Score) }
```

the results are currently ordered by UserId ascending. I'm after Score descending.

thanks :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just add the orderby clause ;-)

```
from a in Audits
join u in Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId
group a by a.UserId into g
let score = g.Sum(x => x.Score)
orderby score descending
select new { UserId = g.Key, Score = score };
```

Comment: I tried just adding an orderby but it didn't work. But what you did was add a LET statement in there! Ahhh.. that's interesting...

Comment: I didn't check, but I don't think the LET is necessary, though. Will just "orderby g.Sum(x => x.Score)" be enough?

Comment: could be, but then i have to have the g.Sum also listed in the select... so is that doing the sum, twice?

Comment: Hey Arjan, whats the difference between your query and query in another one, in terms of performance? which one is better to use in real time applications ?

Comment: I expect performance to be exactly the same. We're still just building the queries here. The query trees will look alike when you actually execute them.

Comment: The "let" allows me to define the aggregate Before the orderby clause so that I can actually sort on it!  Brilliant!  How is this not common knowledge?!  I will write all my linq queries like this from now on.  Cool thing is, your approach supports MULTI-sort with various sort-directions. e.g. "orderby g.Key.UserId ascending, score descending"  Suggestions to wrap the query by chaining OrderBy(), ThenBy(), and OrderByDescending() after it may result in multiple queries instead of one and look less like SQL. FYI: You can add more aggregates by adding another "let" statement below the first one!

Answer (score 13):

```
var results =
 (from a in Audits
join u in Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId
group a by a.UserId into g
select new { UserId = g.Key, Score = g.Sum(x => x.Score) })
.OrderByDescending(p=>p.Score);
```

Hope this will fix your problem, easier than the top one ;)

Cheers

Comment: +1. More than 3 years after this answer has been posted, it helped me today!