# Linq group by and order by create date

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a list of messages in db like so:

FromLoginId, ToLoginId, Message, CreateDate

1. 1, 2, "some message", 2/2/2010
2. 1, 2, "one more", 2/3/2010
3. 4, 2, "from 4 message", 3/4/2010
4. 5, 2, "from 5 mess", 1/3/2010
5. 5, 2, "newer 5", 3/2/2011

I need to have a list of messages grouped by FromLoginId ordered by createDate starting from the newest first.

EDIT: List of messages with the first newest message from the FromLoginId group.

so for example for loginid 2 I would get this result:

FromLoginId, ToLoginId, Message, CreateDate

1. 5, 2, "newer 5", 3/2/2011
2. 4, 2, "from 4 message", 3/4/2010
3. 1, 2, "one more", 2/3/2010

please help.
thanks

Comment: I think this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755132/how-do-i-order-a-group-result-in-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i figured it out. looks ok to me. can anyone please check it?

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.FromLoginId)
   .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreateDate)
   .FirstOrDefault())
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you group by `FromLoginId` you can't display the messages themselves, only the count of them, or any aggregate function that might interest you.